# How exactly type inference is working in java?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

I am trying to create a method like following:

```
public <T> T getInstance(String key) {
   Type type = new TypeToken<T>(){}.getType();
   return deserialize(key, type); }
```

As far as I am not casting `(T)` in `return` statement, I expect compiler to infer type from the outside context or at least from a type witness like here:

```
Integer i = container.<Integer>getInstance(mKey);
```

But for some case, `getInstance()` method returns `Double` that was never mentioned (to be more precise, the serialization and deserialization are using google's [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library, and the initial object was an instance of `Integer`). Hence, I get `ClassCastException`.

So how exactly does type inferring work in this case and why does the type witness not work? Is it possible to infer type from the outside context without specifying `Class<T>.class` as an argument?

**Elaboration:**

After some research, [this FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ050) helped me to understand the topic much better.

Comment: This simply doesn't work. You can't create a type token using a type variable, because of erasure.

Comment: @Andy Turner well, the method compiles. The only problem is the wrong return type. Furthermore, I saw creating TypeToken with generic types from other programmers.

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't compile, I said it doesn't *work*; at least, it doesn't work usefully, as you have found. I should have been more precise in saying you can't create a type token using a type variable *and expect it to capture anything other than the type variable*. Check out [this demonstration](https://ideone.com/chImQ3): the "type" of a "String" type token is the same as the "Integer" type token, because they're capturing the type variable, not the call site type.

Comment: @Andy Turner Ok, I got it, it makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general problem that you have here is that there is nothing to constrain the output to be related to the inputs.

So, this is valid:

```
Integer i = container.<Integer>getInstance(mKey);  // I doubt you even need the <Integer>
```

but this is *also* valid:

```
String s = container.<String>getInstance(mKey);
```

All the `getInstance` method sees is the value of `mKey`: it doesn't know anything about the `<Integer>` or `<String>`; so this has to return the same result in both cases - but at least one of those is wrong (or they are both returning `null`).

---

Because `getInstance` only receives the value of `mKey`, the type token is the same in both cases. You can see this by implementing your own type token class:

```
abstract static class TypeToken<T> {
    Type getType() {
        return getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    }
}

static <T> TypeToken<T> getTypeToken() {
    return new TypeToken<T>() {};
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    TypeToken<String> stringTypeToken = getTypeToken();
    TypeToken<Integer> integerTypeToken = getTypeToken();
    System.out.println(stringTypeToken.getType());
    System.out.println(integerTypeToken.getType());
    System.out.println(stringTypeToken.getType().equals(integerTypeToken.getType()));
}
```

Output:

```
Ideone$TypeToken<T>
Ideone$TypeToken<T>
true
```

In your code, `Type type = new TypeToken<T>(){}.getType();` isn't getting the `TypeToken` for the call site type, it's just getting `T`. So you're not getting a `TypeToken<Integer>`.

This works, in the sense that it compiles, but it doesn't work in the sense that it doesn't do what you're trying to get it to do.

The way to do this correctly is to inject the `TypeToken<T>` as a method parameter. It becomes an awful lot more cumbersome at call sites; but that's the price you pay for using a language with erased types.

Comment: Just wondering, would I be able to send Object as a type to deserializator, but in the return statement cast it to (T) which would be inferred from the outer context?

Comment: I've tried the latter. Also I've tried not to use generics at all and just return Object. Neither works, for some case it still returns Double. Weird.